# How to make a TaskPane Add-in without ribbon button that opens automatically on a document

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I'm creating an internal add-in that needs to automatically open the taskpane when someone opens up a PPTM that will be shared to them. The add-in needs to not have any sort of ribbon/menu buttons which is why it needs to automatically open, but I can't seem to do both of these things at the same time.

I've made the add-in not have any ribbon UI by removing the  part of the manifest file which works, but stops the taskpane from automatically opening.

I've made the add-in automatically open by using
`Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);  Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();`

as well as trying `Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);` in the `Office.initialize` function which both seem to work.

However, when trying to use both in conjunction it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something or is it not possible to have a UI-less taskpane add-in automatically open?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enable/show the task pane for the application, not document (presentation in your case).

You can enable the `autoopen` feature for a particular document only. Don't use the `autoopen` feature to artificially increase usage of your add-in. If it doesn't make sense for your add-in to open automatically with certain documents, this feature can annoy users. If Microsoft detects abuse of the `autoopen` feature, your add-in might be rejected from `AppSource`.

If you need to enable the task pane for a particular document you may find the required steps for that in the [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) article. Note, the `autoopen` feature is currently supported in the following  platforms:

- Office on Windows Desktop. Build 16.0.8121.1000+
- Office on Mac. Build 15.34.17051500+
- Office on the web

If you want to get such feature implemented for the application I'd suggest filing a feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eugene,

I'm aware that add-ins can't be auto-opened per application. I'm just wanting it for a single document that will be shared, and the add-in is for internal use only so I have no worries about that. 

I should have mentioned that I tried the `Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument` but the issue I have is to make the add-in not have any Ribbon button I have to remove the `DesktopFormFactor` part of the manifest, which in turn makes it so I can't use that action. Is there another way I'm missing to stop the add-in from having a Ribbon button?

Comment: You may consider hide/show the ribbon button instead. See [Enable and Disable Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands) for more information.